# I have 2 projects in one solution. One dockerfile does work the other doesn't

Tags: c#, .net, docker

I have 2 projects in one solution. One dockerfile does work the other doesn't
The folder structure is the same

```
Step 6/16 : COPY ["KweetService/KweetService.csproj", "KweetService/"]
Error response from daemon: COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat KweetService/KweetService.csproj: file does not exist
```

Comment: The error is telling you that the file could not be found in the given build context. Are you certain that a file file `KweetService/KweetService.csproj` exists in directory you specified for `docker build`?

Answer (score 0):

The build context, by default, refers to the directory (and all its sub-directories) where Dockerfile itself is.

When you run a Docker build, the Docker client actually gathers the folder into a tarball and sends it to the Docker daemon. So obviously, the Dockerfile can only reference files in this tarball.

Please check that `KweetService/KweetService.csproj` exists relative to the location of the Dockerfile.

If you can provide your project structure, I can edit this response to be more specific.